# Eliminating the Parameter: Transform parametric equation to Cartesian equation and draw arrows along parametric growth

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions

Hey guys I really could use some help on this calc 3 problem. I'm stuck on how to write the code for this problem:

- a) Eliminate the parameter to find a Cartesian equation for a parametric curve.
- b) Sketch the curve and indicate with an arrow the direction in which the curve is traced as the parameter increases.

Given: $x=1-t^2$, $y=t-2$

```
{x == 1 - t^2, y == t - 2}
```

I'm not sure really where to start. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you understand how does the site work.
Is this a Mathematics or a Mathematica question? Did you even try to search in the documentation?

Comment: You mean something like `x=1-t^2=1-(y+2)^2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by using [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html) to remove the parametric variable

```
Eliminate[{x == 1 - t^2, y == t - 2}, t]
```

> -3 - 4 y - y^2 == x

Now you can [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) to get an expression of the form $y(x) = -2 \mp \sqrt{1 - x}$

```
sol = (y /. Solve[-3 - 4 y - y^2 == x, y])
```

> {-2 - Sqrt[1 - x], -2 + Sqrt[1 - x]}

To sketch you will need to know where it crosses the axis

```
sol /. x -> 0
```

> {-3, -1}

That is, it crosses at `{{0, -3}, {0, -1}, {-3, 0}}`. With which slopes?

```
D[sol, x]
```

> ```
> {1/(2 Sqrt[1 - x]), -(1/(2 Sqrt[1 - x]))}
> ```

Slopes are `{1/2, -1/2, -1/4}` respectively.

Now the plot with arrows growing in the same direction as $\hat{y}$, i.e *up*, to the right for $t < -1$ and to the left for $t > 1$

```
Plot[
 sol,
 {x, -9, 2},
 PlotStyle -> Black
 , Frame -> True
 , Prolog -> {Blue, 
   Arrow[Partition[
     Transpose[{1 - t^2, t - 2} /. t -> Range[-5, 5, 0.5]], 2, 1]]}
 , Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
   Point[{{0, -3}, {0, -1}, {-3, 0}}]}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: im still having errors in my code. My solve function seems to not be working. Any ideas on why?

Comment: @Quentin, I can only guess if you don't share your code. People do an effort to help you, do your part. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), make it worthwhile an up vote. Particularly, include a minimum example of the code you are working on that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for this.

```
eqs = {x == 1 - t^2, y == -2 t - 2};
eq1 = Eliminate[eqs, t]
```

> `(-4 - y) y == 4 x`

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eq1, {x, -20, 2}, {y, -12, 12}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
eq2 = {x, y} /. (And @@ eqs // ToRules)
```

> `{1 - t^2, -2 - 2 t}`

```
fig = ParametricPlot[eq2, {t, -5, 5},
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Red],
   Mesh -> True];
fig /. Line[l_] -> {
   Arrowheads[Table[0.1, {i, 0, 1, .2}]], Arrow[l]}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Or you can use this method that got a hint by @rhermans using `Epilog`

```
ParametricPlot[eq2, {t, -5, 5}, MeshStyle -> Red, Mesh -> True,
 Epilog -> Arrow@Partition[Table[eq2, {t, -5, 5, 0.5}], 2]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Are your arrows the wrong direction or mine?

Comment: @rhermans you just use different equations, I used `{x == 1 - t^2, y == -2 t - 2};`