# How to convert a rational parametric plane curve into implicit form?

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, parametric-functions, groebner-bases

This problem is generated from [another Green's theorem related question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342799/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-region-with-a-closed-plane-curve-boundary). And here is a forward of [the same problem in math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342795/how-to-convert-the-parametric-equation-into-implicit-form).

The original equation of the plane curve is not in rational parametric form.

In order to calculate the symbolic solutions of the intersections of the curve itself, I thought its implicit equation form might be helpful or whatever. Nevertheless, such a conversion is interesting itself.

Two articles online are helpful:

1. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.204.9611
2. http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/~xgao/paper/gao-par.pdf

So after simple treatment, I have the following rational parametric equation of the same plane curve as in [another problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342799/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-region-with-a-closed-plane-curve-boundary):

$$\begin{cases}
x=& \dfrac{2 t \left(3 t^4+50 t^2-33\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^3} \\
y=& \dfrac{2 \left(7 t^6-60 t^4+15 t^2+2\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^3} \\
\end{cases}$$

How can I convert it into implicit form :$F(x,y)=0$? My difficulty mainly lies in how to implement it via my familiar computer algebra systems, i.e., *Mathematica*, or Maple.

[The answer by Macaulay2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342795/how-to-convert-the-parametric-equation-into-implicit-form) is definitely acceptable, however, for a beginner like me, there are less documents on the commands than Maple or *Mathematica*.

Comment: The answer is already in one of your tags: `GroebnerBasis[Thread[{x, y} == (* equations *)], {x, y}, t]`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer in Mathematica. But I don't really understand it. Would you please post it as an answer with some explanations so that I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not at a computer now, so I can't write an answer. But I notice that you've been pointed to Cox/Little/O'Shea at math.SE; you'd do well to read that book.

Comment: thank you very much! I need to spend more time on that book so.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61535, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78254/

Comment: Yes, Eliminate also works! thanks

Comment: Just wondering: when will `GroebnerBasis` gain support for F4/F5 methods?

Comment: @kirma, we can only keep hoping…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted, what you want is to use a Gröbner basis to eliminate the parameter:

```
curve = 2 {t (3 t^4 + 50 t^2 - 33), 7 t^6 - 60 t^4 + 15 t^2 + 2}/(t^2 + 1)^3;
implicit = GroebnerBasis[Thread[{x, y} == curve], {x, y}, t] // First
   550731776 - 41620992 x^2 + 585816 x^4 + 625 x^6 - 182250 x^4 y -
   41620992 y^2 + 1171632 x^2 y^2 + 1875 x^4 y^2 + 364500 x^2 y^3 +
   585816 y^4 + 1875 x^2 y^4 - 36450 y^5 + 625 y^6
```

To check that the implicit equation obtained is correct, do this:

```
implicit == 0 /. Thread[{x, y} -> curve] // Simplify
   True
```

If you want to learn more about how Gröbner bases work, [Cox/Little/O'Shea](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-35651-8) is a very good place to start.

---

### Bonus

A simpler set of parametric equations results if you do the Weierstrass substitution:

```
curve2 = curve /. t -> -Tan[u/2] // FullSimplify
   {9 Sin[2 u] + 5 Sin[3 u], 9 Cos[2 u] - 5 Cos[3 u]}
```

I will now guess that you obtained the previous set of equations exactly through the reverse procedure. If you wanted to obtain the implicit Cartesian equation from this, here is what you could have done instead:

```
GroebnerBasis[Append[Thread[{x, y} == curve2] // TrigExpand, Cos[u]^2 + Sin[u]^2 == 1],
              {x, y}, {Cos[u], Sin[u]}] // First
```

and the same implicit expression is returned.

Let's end with a plot:

```
ParametricPlot[{9 Sin[2 u] + 5 Sin[3 u], 9 Cos[2 u] - 5 Cos[3 u]},
               {u, -π, π}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
               PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[7/19, 37/73, 22/31]]]
```

[image: a star is born]